# How to only delete files in a path using batch commands?

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-line, windows-console

I want to delete all the files given a folder's path in batch that are older than 2 days. But I don't want to delete the files that are in subfolders of the path. I am using the following command in batch:

`forfiles /P "Path/to/folder" /S /M *.* /D -2 /C "cmd /c del @path"`

But this is also deleting files and are part of the subfolders of the path which I don't want to do. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `/S` parameter from your `forfiles` command. (See `forfiles /?` for more information.)